# Commands missing in man-pages (blank spaces in manuals)

Tags: debian, terminal, man

When opening man-pages, the page is displayed but all commands are missing.
Spots where refered commands should be are just blanked out.

Running `dpkg-reconfigure manpages` and `apt-get install --reinstall manpages` have not resolve the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The text is there, but the pager shows bold text in black, which happens to be the same colour as your background.

Adjust the colour of either bold text or of the background in your terminal.

How you do this is dependent on what terminal emulator you are using, but I'm assuming there will be a menu somewhere with options for configuring terminal colours, either in the terminal application itself or in an associated configuration panel.

Comment: I'm feeling stupid about this one....

Comment: @littlecoce Well, don't. It was an issue and you did not know cause or solution. Now you do, and so will others with the same issue in the future. All is well and as it should be.